# Can't Create/write to file

Tags: mysql, sql, file-permissions, codio

I'm new to coding and I am having trouble I think granting permission. I am trying to write an SQL statement to list the contents of the orders table and send the output to a file that has a .csv extension. But I keep getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on what you are asking but found below solution through google:

Try the following:

1. mkdir /var/lib/mysql/tmp
2. chmod mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/tmp
3. Add the following line into the [mysqld] section: tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp
4. Restart the server